# Fail to automatically resize NSTextField under NSView (as menu item)

Tags: text, height, nsview, nstextfield

I am an **inexperienced** user trying to learn via the simple projects creation process... I request your assistance as I have not found a working solution for two whole days now, digging the Xcode Help and Google.

I have a simple MacOS X (10.6.x) application that creates (in-code) an extra NSMenuItem to the XIB status bar menu. On my AppDelegate, I create an object that loads the NSView (from MainMenu.xib):

```
// Add menu entry for NSView object
NSMenuItem* newItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Placeholder"
                                        action:nil
                                        keyEquivalent:@""];
[newItem setView:theView];
[newItem setEnabled:NO];
[newItem setTarget:self];
[calendarMenu insertItem: newItem atIndex:0];
[newItem release];
```

In my MainMenu.xib, besides the menu structure, I have another object set as NSView and under it, NSTextField (occupying all the space of the view). The menu seems to load the view window.

Later on, I set some string to NSTextField but I cannot adjust the height accordingly; it's either too much or crops:

```
// Crop last newline character
NSString *menuCelebrations = [NSString stringWithString:
        [celebName substringToIndex:([celebName length] - 1)]];
NSFont *msgFont = [NSFont menuBarFontOfSize:12.0];

// Set attributes
[theTextField setFont:msgFont];
[theTextField setStringValue:menuCelebrations];
```

The top menu now displays the longer text that I want, wrapped etc. but I cannot adjust the height properly with something like:

```
theView setFrame: NSMakeRect([theView frame].origin.x,
            [theView frame].origin.y,
            calendarMenu.size.width,
            newHeightFloat)];
```

As a newbie, I tried things like these for automatic resize, but to no avail obviously:

```
[theTextField sizeToFit];
[theTextField autoresizesSubviews];
[theView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewHeightSizable];
[theView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

Needless say that I tried numerous attribute-combinations in Interface Builder (where the text field resizes with the view etc.). Nothing worked... I still cannot figure out a way to **calculate and set the height** to either NSView or NSTextFieled that is the sub-object.

I found ideas and code over here at [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) and [www.cocoabuilder.com](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/) but people mention the use of NSLayoutManager, NSTextStorage and NSTextContainer that Apple suggests somewhere in the documentation (look for chapter/reference "Calculating Text Height" that has some code, but fails to be implemented); others suggest that Apple's calculates the box but rendering that box does miss some pixels at the bottom.

A [reference](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/153626-text-height-for-printing-fixed-width.html) to Matt Neuburg's work (instead of NSLayout that Apple suggests) that makes proper calculation (with a sample project) seems to work well but on NSTextView objects...

Must I create a separate/custom class for this NSView? Should I prefer NSTextView to NSTextField?

Did anyone manage to adjust the height (only) to the proper size? I would surely appreciate some help with a code sample.

Am I digging **too deep without proper understanding** of the methods in place?